# Color of the .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor can't be changed

Tags: typeahead.js

I have to change the color of the font of the `.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor` and remove it's background.

The following CSS doesn't work:

```
.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
   color: #009bc6;
}
```

Comment: instead of giving the of names of classes, tell us what it is that you exactly want to change. Because changing `.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor` does work here http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/pegp21r7/18/

Answer (score 0):

> **CAUSE**

This have been changed in typeahead version 0.11, moving mouse over `.tt-suggestion` element no longer triggers `.tt-cursor` class, see [this issue #1195](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1195).

> **SOLUTION**

```
// WORKAROUND: Add support for tt-cursor style on mouseenter/mouseleave
$('.twitter-typeahead')
   .on('mouseenter', '.tt-suggestion', function(e){
      $('.tt-cursor', $(this).closest('.tt-menu')).removeClass('tt-cursor');
      $(this).addClass('tt-cursor');
   })                  
   .on('mouseleave', '.tt-menu', function(e){
      $('.tt-cursor', $(this).closest('.tt-menu')).removeClass('tt-cursor');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a [contributor](https://github.com/jharding),

> Yep this was intentional. It was done to make it clear that hovering over a suggestion and keying down to it are different. For example the latter will change the display value in the input whereas the former will not.

See this [issue](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1195).

You can style your items like so:

```
.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor, 
.tt-suggestion:hover {
    // property: value;
}
```